# What is the standard setting for the Ele stick in FPV mode

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, first-person-view, control-input

I've been flying quads for quite a while both line of sight and FPV. I started with Liftoff simulator FPV where I had the settings set the way that when I move the Ele stick backwards, the drone moves forward (inverted settings?). The inverted setting in FPV made more sense to me back then because the camera followed the stick.

Then I moved to line of sight flying and found the inverted stick counterintuitive. The observed drone moves in a different direction than the stick. So I learned to fly LOS in normal Ele setting.

Now I prefer normal Ele setting in LOS and inverted Ele setting in FPV and I'm wondering if  I should force myself to learn to fly in non-inverted Ele setting in FPV. I think the normal setting might give a better control over a drone if you imagine it's position in space, but that's just my assumption. On the other hand in this setting camera moves the other way than the Ele stick which feels kind of weird.

What settings do professional drone pilots use for a better control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short answer

The standard is that pulling the elevator stick backwards lifts the front of the quad, the same as an airplane (pull up). This is the same regardless of LOS/FPV/otherwise.

## Longer answer

REalistically, whatever works for you is fine. Back in the days before electronic reversal, people would notoriously learn with the elevator backwards (this is fixed wing, so "push up"). This was either done because they thought this was correct (as you are thinking here), or because they couldn't reverse the mechanism and so had no choice. Some people still fly that way, however I would not feel comfortable handing someone the transmitter to one of my expensive machines if they were wary that their instinct might kick in and they push the machine nose first (this has happened to me, surprisingly with a military pilot who learned on real aircraft).

If it's more intuitive to you, and allows you to move forward in the hobby, then fine. However, it limits your ability to pick up someone else's machine and fly it. Same goes for "mode 2" transmitters which most of north america uses - their are arguments for and against any mode, but unless you have a compelling reason to switch, the disadvantages are negligible to comply with a majority-backed standard

Comment: Alright, I'm not looking for the the easy solution, but for the proper one :) It looks like I have to fly my way through it. Now that I know which is the right way, it shouldn't be too hard to switch. Probably a few hours on a simulator. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For a standard manned aircraft moving the control stick forward would push the nose of the aircraft down. This replicates the directions you would move  your head in order to look up (head back) and down (head foward).
I don't know that there is any other "standard" besides that. Whatever works the best for you would be my recommendation.

Comment: Moving your head forward causes you to look down.

Comment: Ah, you caught me. That is what I get for not proofreading !